# How to assign matplotlib.pyplot.table to separate subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to print a series of tables on a figure using `matplotlib.pyplot.table` but I'm getting tables covered up by empty subplots like in this example:

[image]

The code I'm using right now goes like this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4)
labels = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
frames = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]
for (idx, label), tab in zip(enumerate(labels), frames):
                vals = tab.astype('str').values
                axs[idx].table(cellText=vals, rowLabels=tab.index,
                               colLabels=tab.columns)
```

An example of individual dataframe I'm trying to tabulate looks like this:

```
   Tonnes      Fe       P    SiO2   Al2O3     LOI
0  613012  1.5422  1.3614  0.5025  0.7374  1.2856
1   11404  0.9654  0.9750  1.0866  0.8366  2.2400
2   13469  0.9792  0.9686  1.2066  0.7302  1.7702
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

To deal with this situation, you can set the position of the table for a single graph using `bbox=[left,bottom,width,height]`. Then you can set the subplot spacing. I set the graph size and adjusted each parameter manually because the default size of the graph collapses the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(6,9))
labels = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4 = df.copy(),df.copy(),df.copy(),df.copy()

frames = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]
for (idx, label), tab in zip(enumerate(labels), frames):
                vals = tab.astype('str').values
                axs[idx].table(cellText=vals,
                               rowLabels=tab.index,
                               colLabels=tab.columns,
                               loc='bottom',
                               bbox=[0.0,-2.75,1.0,2.0])
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=3.0)
```

[image]